# Selenium-cucumber.js test failed to run while adding a BeforeScenario in hooks.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, cucumberjs

Framework using: **selenium-cucumber-js**.
    I am trying to run the below selenium-cucumber-js test. I would like to run the `loginApp()` function as `BeforeScenario` written in hooks.js file. But while running the test, its throwing below error at the moment. Could someone please advise on how to resolve the problem.

```
`C:\Tests\cucumber\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\runtime\event_broadcaster.js:30 process.nextTick(function(){ throw error; }); // prevent swallow by unhandled rejection                                        
TypeError: node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\support_code\library.js:17 scenario.loginApp is not a function
    at C:\Tests\cucumber\step-definitions\hooks.js:4:51
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)`

/**/Feature:**

//cucumber/features
```

Feature: Login and look for the Register tab

```
 Scenario: Check the register tab in application
    When After login look for "Register" in navbar


//**lookfortab.js**

//cucumber/step-definitions

    const expect = require('chai').expect;
    module.exports = function() {
        this.When(/^After login look for "([^"]*)" in navbar$/, function (registerText) {
        let navText = By.css('div#nav>div>ul>li>a');
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(navText, 10000));
        return driver.findElement(navText).getText().then(el => {                   
           console.log("print text here:"+el);     
           const displayTxt = el;  
           expect(displayTxt).to.be.eql(registerText);                  
            });     

        })

    }

//login.js

//cucumber/page-objects


    module.exports = {  
        loginApp(){
          this.driver.helpers.loadPage('https://testingsite.com')     
          this.driver.findElement(by.id('HomeLogin_Username')).sendKeys("Tester");
          this.driver.findElement(by.id('HomeLogin_Password')).sendKeys("SomePassword123");     
          let lgBtn = By.css('div#login-fields>div>button');
          this.driver.findElement(lgBtn).click();    
        }   

    };

//hooks.js

//cucumber/step-definitions


    module.exports = function () {
        this.BeforeScenario(function(scenario, done) {
            console.log('BeforeScenario: ' + scenario.loginApp());
            done();
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that `selenium-cucumber-js` is using a rather old version of `cucumber-js` (1.3.3 vs 5.0.2 at the moment of writing this). Keep that in mind when you're consulting `cucumber-js` docs or looking for examples. Below, I'll be posting links to the `cucumber-js@1.3.3` docs.

As for what's not working in your set up:

1. `scenario` object that is passed into your hooks doesn't have page objects attached to it. It only contains some meta info about the scenario and methods to get it. Here's a list of them: [cucumber-js docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/44667d92394938cab50170a504749ded7f4ab252/lib/cucumber/api/scenario.js#L27-L41)
2. If you want to reference the page objects from your hooks, you can use the global `page` as described here: [Page objects - selenium-cucumber-js](https://github.com/john-doherty/selenium-cucumber-js#page-objects)
3. Your `loginApp()` function probably still won't work because you're accessing webdriver as `this.driver` and helpers as `this.driver.helpers`. They're also globally defined by `selenium-cucumber-js`: [Helpers](https://github.com/john-doherty/selenium-cucumber-js#helpers)

So, your `hooks.js` should look like this:

```
module.exports = function () {
  this.BeforeScenario(function(scenario, done) {
    console.log('BeforeScenario: ' + page.login.loginApp());
    done();
  });

};
```

And your `login.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  loginApp(){
    helpers.loadPage('https://example.com')
    driver.findElement(by.id('HomeLogin_Username')).sendKeys("Tester");
    driver.findElement(by.id('HomeLogin_Password')).sendKeys("SomePassword123");
    let lgBtn = By.css('div#login-fields>div>button');
    driver.findElement(lgBtn).click();
  }

};
```

Comment: Thank you very much..now the test is passing..but at this step  `console.log('BeforeScenario: ' + page.login.loginApp());` is throwing undefined ..do you why this is throwing undefined at this step in hooks.js?

Comment: @soccerway what's the error message and call stack?

Comment: I don't get any other error log in command prompt, only this one `BeforeScenario: undefined
[988044:985184:1126/105221.299:ERROR:install_util.cc(691)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)`

Comment: @soccerway Ok, I see. `loginApp()` prints `undefined` because it doesn't return anything. If a function doesn't return anything explicitly, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: I have a set of login steps in that `loginApp()` and doesn't return anything. In this case what should I need to return ?

Comment: @soccerway I don't know. What do you want to achieve? What do you want your `console.log()` to output there? Or do you just want to login in in the hooks?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to login using my hooks. Nothing is expected to return

Comment: @soccerway so leaving `page.login.loginApp()` should do the trick then - in case it works

Comment: Cool that worked, if we give it console and console was expecting something to return to print which ideally was not happening, so it displays `undefined`. Is it right ?